# TypeError: Can only call Node.addEventListener on instances of Node on Safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs, safari

I have this piece of code in my React component that disables the "enter" key.

```
export const attachDisableEnterEvent = (ref) => {
  const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(ref);
  // Evergreen event listener || IE8 event listener
  const addEvent = node.addEventListener || node.attachEvent;
  addEvent('keypress', _disableEnter, false);
}
```

It works fine on Chrome / Firefox, but not Safari. On Safari I get :-

> TypeError: Can only call Node.addEventListener on instances of Node

---

I could only get it to work (on all fronts) by doing this :-

```
addEvent.call(node, 'keypress', _disableEnter, false);
```

Just wondering why is the implementation for `addEventListener` different on Chrome & Safari. It seems like `Node.addEventListener` on Chrome will just intuitively bind `this` to the node instance that defined it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably the same reason why we have the following:

```
var log = console.log;
log('foo') // TypeError
```

Instead, we have to:

```
var log = console.log.bind(console); // bind console.log function to it's proper context
log('foo') // 'foo'
```

In your case, calling

```
addEvent('keypress', _disableEnter, false);
```

causes the context to be the window object (implicitly).

In general you always want to bind your function first to the owning object when you intend to pass it off to someone else. Browser implementations are different for each browser, so that is the best way to ensure that it works uniformly.

In the console case, I believe that .log refers to other instance methods on the console object itself. And so in Safari, the `node.addEventListener` function may be implemented in a way that needs other functions only defined on `node`, and they probably threw in a more descriptive error message as well.

So instead you should do:

```
const addEvent = node.addEventListener || node.attachEvent;
const boundAddEvent = addEvent.bind(node);
// use boundAddEvent however you like anywhere, or .call like you did
```

Comment: Ahh I get it. So it was actually calling `window.addEventListener` and I thought it behaved the same :p

Comment: So now the question is why Safari treats `window` differently than chrome? :p So it seems like Safari doesn't treat `window` as a `Node`